# WebdriverIO: Execution context is not available in detached frame

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, automation, puppeteer, webdriver-io

I'm trying to automate a flow that I've been doing at least once a day for the past 3 years. It's an unnecessarily convoluted process that is taking time out of my day. It's an internal proprietary system, so I can't give you any details about it, but suffice to say that I cannot change it. I have to try to automate it the way it is, and I'm stuck with the following error:

```
Execution context is not available in detached frame "https://..." (are you trying to evaluate?)
```

I'm using WebdriverIO with the default configuration, which uses Puppeteer internally. When I googled the error, I got a suggestion to add the following flags:

```
'--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'
```

I did that, but it didn't help:

```
remote({
    logLevel: 'trace',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process']
        }
    }
})
```

I want to try it out in the REPL to do some more debugging, but I haven't figured out how to add those args when launching the REPL:

```
npx wdio repl chrome
```

Everything I've tried so far has failed. If someone knows how to do it, please let me know.

I don't do web automation normally and I chose WebdriverIO, since I have used it in the past for mobile automation. I'm wondering if this is a Puppeteer specific issue and if it would work in Selenium, but I'm not quite sure how to set that up. Puppeteer was just working out of the box.

Any guidance on how to get past this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was pretty simple:

```
browser.switchToFrame($('#iFrame'))
// Doing stuff inside the frame that causes the next page to show.
// Now that iFrame is gone and I have to switch out of it, to continue:
browser.switchToParentFrame()
// After the above call the execution context is not in a detached frame anymore.
```